# SSH into a windows machine without password

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh

I want to SSH into a windows 10 machine running OpenSSh server. However, this machine has no password because it is used for automation and must start and login without user interaction. So when I try to use SSH to access it, I'm asked for the password and cannot give one as the host machine doesn't have one. Entering an empty password is also denied.

I do not have much experience with SSH so I hope this is an easy fix that I just cannot find because all results on google lead to results where people just dont want to enter their password everytime they ssh into the machine.

Comment: I do not think that OpenSSH allows login with password-less accounts.

Comment: Windows 10 does not allow network connections without a password.